# how to write a multi-row equation with a lot of material in each row

Tags: equations

```
\[
\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z)*\left( \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} + \frac{\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}\right) \right]
\]

\[
=\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z)*\left( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p+1) z^k - D \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k  +\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\right) \right] 
\]

\[
=\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z)*\left( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}  z^k + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k z^k  +p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} z^k\right) \right] 
\]


\[
=\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z) + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k \alpha _k z^k  +p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} \alpha _k z^k \right] \]

\[
=\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ zf^{'}(z) (1-D) - \beta e^{i\theta }(1-D)(zf^{'}(z)-pf(z)) + (1+pD-p)f(z) \right] 
\]
```

Comment: you need to use array... than you will be able to split the equation in multiple lines.

Comment: never put display environments one one after another, use `align` here (from amsmath package) also `f^{'}` should be `f'`

Answer (score 5):

Another amsmath possibility:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{z^p}&\Bigl[ f(z)*\Bigl( \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} +
 \frac{\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}\Bigr) \Bigr]\\[\jot]
&{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ f(z)*\Bigl( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p+1) z^k
                        - D \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\\
&\qquad
                          {}+\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\bigr)\Bigr]
\\[\jot]
&{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ f(z)*\Bigl( z^p +\\
& \qquad  \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}  z^k + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k z^k
  +p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} z^k\Bigr) \Bigr]
\\[\jot]
&=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ f(z) + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k \alpha _k z^k  +
p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} \alpha _k z^k \Bigr] \\[\jot]
&=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ zf'(z) (1-D) - \beta e^{i\theta }(1-D)(zf'(z)-pf(z)) + (1+pD-p)f(z) \Bigr] 
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: would look better with the first line shoved left a bit.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know, but was in a hurry:-) Can you suggest an edit?

Comment: it's pretty wide, so there's not much room to fiddle.  two possibilities: in the first line, move the `&` just after the `\Bigl[`; or call `mathtools` instead of `amsmath` and wrap `\mathllap` around the same chunk.

Comment: @barbarabeeton done; it's a bit over full but I won't tell if you don't.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `align` here or `align*`, if you do not want to get the lines numbered. These environments are part of the package `amsmath`. You could load the package `mathtools` instead in order to move the first row to the left. Looks nicer in my eyes. Just adapt the `[number]` of `\MoveEqLeft` to your needs:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft[4]\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)\biggl( \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} + \frac{\beta\e^{i\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}\biggr) \biggr]\\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)\biggl( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p+1) z^k - D \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\\
    &\hphantom{{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[}+\beta \e^{i\theta}(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\biggr) \biggr]\\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)\biggl( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} z^k + (1- \beta\e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k z^k\\
    &\hphantom{{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[}+p(1-\beta\e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} z^k\biggr) \biggr]\\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z) + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k \alpha_k z^k\\
    &\hphantom{{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[}+p(1-\beta\e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} \alpha _k z^k \biggr]\\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ zf'(z) (1-D) - \beta\e^{i\theta}(1-D)(zf'(z)-pf(z))\\
    &\hphantom{{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[}+(1+pD-p)f(z) \Bigr]
    \end{align*}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, you could replace all instances of `&\hphantom{{}=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[}+` with `&\qquad`.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I had that in the first version. But I did not like it that much. But a good information for the OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you make the following adjustments:

- Most importantly, use an `align*` environment instead of consecutive `\[ ... \]` constructs. Use `\qquad` to indent the subsidiary lines of each equation.
- You have some redundant parentheses in several of the equations. Keep things as visually uncluttered as possible -- you only need one large pair, not two.
- The subscripts below the 8 [!] `\sum` symbols are wider than the symbol itself, leading to a lot of wasted (and probably undesirable) whitespace on either side of the summation signs. Encase the subscript terms in `\mathclap{...}` (a macro of the `mathtools` package) to keep this from happening.
- Don't use `\left` and `\right` to size the parentheses, as they'll give you parentheses that are too large, typographically speaking. Use `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead.
- Optional: Some people suggest (insist?!) that the letters for Euler's number `e` and the imaginary number `i` be typeset in an upright font. If you do so, it's handy to create macros called, say, `\e` and `\im`, for this purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}       % for '\mathclap' macro
\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}  % typeset Euler's number in upright font
\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm{i}} % ditto for the square root of -1

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{z^p}\, f(z)
    &*\biggl[ \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} + \frac{\beta\e^{\im\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}\biggr] \\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\, f(z)*\biggl[ z^p + \sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} (k-p+1) z^k - D \sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\\
    &\qquad +\beta \e^{\im\theta}(D-1)\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\biggr] \\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p} \, f(z)*\biggl[ z^p + \sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} z^k + (1- \beta\e^{\im\theta})(1-D) \sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}k z^k\\
    &\qquad+p(1-\beta\e^{\im\theta})(D-1)\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} z^k\biggr] \\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z) + (1- \beta\e^{\im\theta})(1-D) \sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}k \alpha_k z^k\\
    &\qquad +p(1-\beta\e^{\im\theta})(D-1)\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} \alpha _k z^k \biggr]\\
    &=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ zf'(z) (1-D) - \beta\e^{\im\theta}(1-D)\bigl(zf'(z)-pf(z)\bigr)\\
    &\qquad +(1+pD-p)f(z) \Bigr]
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would much more prefer the "tails" aligned to the very right, which can be done by `\\ && \mathllap{ blabla \biggr]} `

Comment: @tohecz - I considered performing alignment on the right-hand ends, but then the big summation signs start tangling with each other unless one increases the interline distance considerably. (But if one increases the interline space, "visual holes" start to appear on the left.) Maybe doubling the indent of the secondary lines, i.e., going from `\qquad` to `\qquad\qquad` ("quadruple \quad"?!) would be a reasonable compromise...

Comment: ah ok I see, that'd be really bad.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to break the beast into smaller pieces, add comments and explain. It as well allows you to simplify the formulas:

[image]

Two comments:

1. I didn't insert any explanatory text, you will have to do that yourself.
2. If the star `*` doesn't denote convolution, but rather standard multiplication, simply remove it, it's redundant and it can be even confusing.

The code follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

We have that
\begin{multline*}
    \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} + \frac{\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}
\\
    = z^p + \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} (k-p+1) z^k - D \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k
    +\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)\:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k
\\
    = z^p + \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}  z^k + (1-\beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}k z^k
    +p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} z^k
\end{multline*}
 and
\begin{multline*}
    f(z)*\biggl(\! z^p + \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}  z^k + (1-\beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}k z^k
    + p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} z^k \biggr)
\\
    = f(z) + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty}k \alpha _k z^k
    + p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\:\sum_{\mathclap{k=p+1}}^{\infty} \alpha _k z^k
\\
    = zf'(z) (1-D) - \beta e^{i\theta }(1-D)\bigl(zf'(z)-pf(z)\bigr) + (1+pD-p)f(z)
,\end{multline*}
 therefore
\begin{multline*}
    \frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)*\Bigl( \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} + \frac{\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}\Bigr) \biggr]
\\
    =\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ zf'(z) (1-D) - \beta e^{i\theta }(1-D)\bigl(zf'(z)-pf(z)\bigr) + (1+pD-p)f(z) \Bigr]
.\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `geometry` package and employ that package's default (or even narrower) margin settings, the equations all fit between the margins without having to break lines. Alternatively, you can use the `medsize` environment (from `nccmath`,  ~80 % of \displaystyle):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe,nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand*{\e}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[4]\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)\biggl( \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)²} + \frac{β \e^{iθ}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)²}\biggr) \biggr]\\
&=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)\biggl( z^p + ∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞} (k-p+1) z^k - D ∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞} (k-p) z^k+β \e^{iθ}(D-1)∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞} (k-p) z^k\biggr) \biggr]\\
&=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z)\biggl( z^p + ∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞} z^k + (1- β \e^{i θ })(1-D) ∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞}k z^k+p(1-β \e^{iθ})(D-1)∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞} z^k\biggr) \biggr]\\
&=\frac{1}{z^p}\biggl[ f(z) + (1- β e^{i θ })(1-D) ∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞}k α_k z^k + p(1-β \e^{iθ})(D-1)∑ _{k=p+1}^{∞} α _k z^k \biggr]\\
&=\frac{1}{z^p}\Bigl[ zf'(z) (1-D) - β \e^{iθ}(1-D)(zf'(z)-pf(z))+(1+pD-p)f(z) \Bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your explanation a bit to draw a bit more attention to assumption that `geometry` package is in use. Hope that's OK. Feel free to revert to initial explanation if you prefer it.

Comment: Thanks Mico! I wrote my answer too hastily. I must say that without geometry, the margins are really huge. I thought that geometry without any margin option produced more or less the default.

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be put the pages with extreme long equations/matrices in landscape.
So the required example would become

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\[ \begin{array}{lcc}
\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z)*\left( \frac{z^p - D z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}} + \frac{\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)z^{p+1}}{(1-z)^{2}}\right) \right] & = & 
\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z)*\left( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p+1) z^k - D \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k +\beta e^{i\theta}(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} (k-p) z^k\right) \right] \\ \\
 &=&\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z)*\left( z^p + \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} z^k + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k z^k +p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} z^k\right) \right] \\ \\
 &=&\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ f(z) + (1- \beta e^{i \theta })(1-D) \sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty}k \alpha _k z^k +p(1-\beta e^{i\theta})(D-1)\sum _{k=p+1}^{\infty} \alpha _k z^k \right] \\ \\
&=&\frac{1}{z^p}\left[ zf^{'}(z) (1-D) - \beta e^{i\theta }(1-D)(zf^{'}(z)-pf(z)) + (1+pD-p)f(z) \right]
\end{array} \] 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: What would be the advantage of typesetting these equations in `\textstyle` (the default mode in an `array` environment) rather than in `\displaystyle` (the default mode in an `align` envirnment)?

Comment: I'm desparate to find my **PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS** sign. Rotating equations is a very bad idea. The equation is supposed to be a part of some text, how would this fit in? You would put it on a separate page? Or what? I can't imagine how this can ever look reasonable.

Comment: I know it is not a recommended for scientific or official publications but is still an option... The pdf continue printable. Sometimes I prefer to flip a monoghraph rather than see data split in multiple lines.